# Log in to multiple remote servers and execute a script

Tags: ssh, shell-script

I want to make a script that will remote login to the multiple servers listed in a txt file like

```
10.3.9.6
10.3.9.7
```

and all servers have same username and password.
and want to capture the output of each script of each server to the server which is executing the script.